# SQL Developer worksheet text goes invisible randomly

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

[image: ISSUE GIF]
SQL Developer Version-  **Version 3.2.20.09 Build MAIN-09.87**

Comment: Which operating system is that, and which Java version are you using? It might be better to search/ask on [the SQL Developer forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/sql_developer). Though if there is a bug, you'd probably get a fix by upgrading to a more recent version.

Comment: @AlexPoole That is UBUNTU 14.04 with java version 1.6.0_33. I dont think i can go beyond this version of sql developer without upgrading  my java.